# Gitlab-Python Api. After creating MR cant get actual MR status info

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

Im creating MR with python-gitlab. After creation i need to check for mr_conflicts and pipeline state.

```
project = gl.projects.get(PROJECT_ID, lazy=False)
create_mr = project.mergerequests.create({'id': PROJECT_ID,
                                      'title': 'Testing multiMR',
                                      'source_branch': SOURCE_BRANCH,
                                      'target_branch': TARGET_BRANCH,
                                      'labels': [LABEL]})
mr_iid = getattr(create_mr, 'iid')

time.sleep(3)

get_mr = project.mergerequests.get(mr_iid)
mr_conflict = getattr(get_mr, 'has_conflicts')
mr_pipeline = getattr(get_mr, 'pipeline', 'No pipeline')
```

But I dont get actual info with this requests! I have answer with data like MR was created just now and has no info about coflicts or pipelines.

Same time if i start another script from different console only for checking MR status i got right actual information.

Another moment. If in the script with MR creation i run cycle

```
n = 4
while n > 0: 
  
  time.sleep(1)
  n -= 1
  project.refresh()
  get_mr = project.mergerequests.get(mr_iid)
  mr_conflict = get_mr.has_conflicts
  mr_pipeline = getattr(get_mr, 'pipeline', 'No pipeline')
```

still no updated info.

How can i get actual info about MR inside script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes of an MR object will not refresh/update themselves. You must request the information with the API again (create a new object)

```
my_mr = project.mergerequests.create(...)
mr_iid = my_mr.iid
# later
...
# get current data from the server
mr_info = project.mergerequests.get(mr_iid) 
print(mr_info.attributes)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did. 
Sorry i didnt add this string in question
`get_mr = project.mergerequests.get(mr_iid)`
And i got wrong old data about MR

Comment: @Dim you have to do the `.get` inside the loop.

Comment: Something is wrong or i dont understand thing
Tried your advice and had no effect.
I corrected my topic info. Is that way you meant i should do for update MR info?

Comment: @Dim what makes you believe it is not working? What is the behavior you're expecting and what is the behavior you are observing?

Comment: Your advice worked, thank you 

I was confused by output of this string 
`mr_pipeline = getattr(get_mr, 'pipeline', 'No pipeline')`